# Visual Studio 2019 Model browser freeze/hang

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

The model browser in Visual Studio 2019 has started to freeze/hang when ever I try to open it for any of my EDXM-files.

This is what it looks like:

[image: Model browser empty]]

This problem was not present when I first installed VS2019, everything was working fine. It came after a month or so. Maybe with an update. Co-workers running the same OS (Win10), same VS2019 version (16.1.5) are not having this problem.

I've tried to repair the VS2019 installation but no changes. I've created brand new EDMX-files and new projects trying to get around the problem, with no luck.

Anybody has any idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1):

Sloppy googling on my part... Found the answer here:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/578666/edmx-model-browser-not-working-in-version-161.html

Workaround: uncheck Envrionment->General->Optimize rendering for screens...